# dplyr: row_number() not working with sql table (SQLite)

Tags: sql, r, sqlite, dplyr, tidyverse

If I want to create a new column containing observation numbers with data frames I can,

```
mtcars %>% mutate(i=row_number())
```

But row_number() does not work with sql tables.

```
mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "")
dbWriteTable(mydb, "mt", mtcars)
mt.sql=tbl(mydb, "mt")
mt.sql %>% mutate(i=row_number())
```

Error:

> Window function `row_number()` is not supported by this database

Would there be any other ways around this problem?

Comment: can you use `1:n(.)` instead?

Comment: Error: Window function `n()` is not supported by this database

Comment: interesting... also `dim(mt.sql)` returns `c(NA, 11)`...

Comment: have you had a look at [this discussion about a similar topic](https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/2960)?

Comment: I think in SQL you can't know the number of rows of an output without running the query, so I suppose it would go against the lazy evaluation principles of dplyr with data bases. you could run the query `SELECT COUNT*
FROM mt` directly . or `alter table ...` if you want to modify the table on your server

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper Then it should work if i do `mt.sql %>% select(everything()) %>% mutate(i=row_number())` ?

Answer (score 0):

You could work around it by using SQLite syntax like this

```
RSQLite::dbSendQuery(mydb, "ALTER TABLE mt ADD COLUMN i INTEGER")
RSQLite::dbSendQuery(mydb, "UPDATE mt SET (i) = ROWID")
```

Then you can go on using `dplyr` syntax like after re-assigning `mt` from your db connection to the `mt.sql` object.

```
mt.sql=tbl(mydb, "mt")
mt.sql %>% select(mpg, i) # e.g.
```

Comment: I am trying to write a function to do calculations on sql tables hence im using dplyr. I would need the function to work on regular dfs aswell. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite doesn't support row number function.

Comment: But what does this mean?
https://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-window-functions/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `mtcars %>% mutate(i=row_number(desc(disp)))`?
It works for me even in SQL.